# VS2012 All packages(Nuget) are already installed and there is nothing to restore

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget-package

I was debugging a project when my computer crashed with a blue screen. After the crash I had to recover my files from a backup. My computer was restored to its original settings. Then I started to get the following errors when compiling

```
NuGet package restore started.
All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
NuGet package restore finished.
HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)
```

So I googled for the error and according to instructions deleted files from Temp and ASPWEBADMIN folders. This solved the HRESULT error and my project is running normally except that when I compile and debug any project I still get the `NUGET package restore`. I googled for solution and landed on this [**Link**](https://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/2ffdc1093fc4b6558ecaf096523d4405b3c3c6d9). But I am not sure how to use this link. I want to know

1) Is this Build Output a problem? (If it aint broke dont fix it)

2) If it is a problem do u know any solution.

Comment: 8 years later, and we still have to do hours of manual NuGet package remove/re-add updates... Making sure we carefully uninstall packages in-order, due to their dependencies. Then remember the needed version & reinstall. Right-click solution >> "Restore NuGet Packages" is seemingly worthless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by going to Tools and updating NUGET PACKAGES also performed a Visual Studio manual Update.